# Fonts are not displaying properly in Firefox, However in Chrome and IE are working fine

Tags: html, firefox, fonts

Fonts got decompress with Firefox but in Chrome and IE fonts are working fine. Specifically the paragraph fonts. Please have a look at my HTML Code. P.S: Marquee is working fine, no issues with that.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>STACKFLOW</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color:#808080;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#banner {
width: 75%;
height: 200px;
float: right;
}
img.c1 {width: 1005px; height: 175px; display: block;}
img.c2 {width: 1010px; height: 175px; display: block;}

h1 {
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff;
left: 20px;
top: 0px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 50px;
float:left;
}
p.cn {
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 22px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffd700;
left: 20px;
top: 80px;
float: left;
}
span {color: #ffd700;}
span.g {color:#ffffff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffd700;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
<marquee loop="true" direction="up" scrollamount="2"   onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
<img src="handshake1.jpg" alt="hanshake" class="c1"><img src="help.jpg"   alt="help.jpg" class="c1"></img></marquee>
</div>
<h1 class="h1"><span>S</span><span class="g">TACKS</span></h1>
<p class="cn">Network&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Community</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like

```
font-size-adjust: inherit;
font-size-adjust: 0.58;
```

It should help, there is more information you can look into here:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust
```

Comment: Thanks Much Jon, let me try out this. However I have some problem with links, let me post into another thread